# How to import Scringo library in Xamarin or Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, import, xamarin

i'm new to android development and i'm using Xamarin and Android Studio ... i have created my Hello World App successfully and i have downloaded Scringo SDK.
in it's tutorial he is using eclipse.
so in tutorial he said to right click in eclipse workspace and click on import.
but i'm using Xamarin and i can't find Import option.
please if anyone has any idea tell me :). thanks and sorry for my English.

http://cdn1.scringo.com/resources/v1/import.jpg

where i can find this import option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a C# to Java binding project. It is very easy but might need some tweaking depending on the Java library.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/