# Using Scringo in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, scringo

I'm trying to use Scringo SDK in my project to enable user chat. However I am using Android Studio for the project and currently stuck at how to actually enable my project to depend on the SDK provided by Scringo. In the documentation, the provided guide is using Eclipse to import the library project.

Plus, with my lack of experience with Gradle and Android Studio, I am unable to solve this. I've tried following this guide and it does not work. [How to import eclipse library project from github to android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310164/how-to-import-eclipse-library-project-from-github-to-android-studio-project)

Can anyone experienced with this kind of issue provide a step-by-step guide on how to curb this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import Scringo library in Xamarin or Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633773/how-to-import-scringo-library-in-xamarin-or-android-studio)

Comment: @ScottBarta I dont think it's answering my question as the answer is specifically for Xamarin user. No android studio solution provided over there.